# removeClass if div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="slider">some here</div>
<div id="slider-2" class="ativa desativa">here too
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function isEmpty( el ){
        return !$.trim(el.html())
    }
    if (isEmpty($('#slider'))) {
        $("#slider-2").removeClass("desativa");
        $("#slider-2").addClass("ativa");
    } else {
        $("#slider-2").removeClass("ativa");
        $("#slider-2").addClass("desativa");
    }

</script>
```

i need to show a div, if another div is empty. I thought that thing of remove and add classe could work.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see what is going wrong? Set  breakpoints and single step.

Comment: Your syntax makes no sense. Format it You have random { and }

Comment: the `isEmpty` is easy to write directly, making such a function is no need.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing:

```
if (isEmpty($('#slider'))) {
```

to:

```
if (isEmpty($('.slider'))) {
```

Looks like `slider` is a class in your HTML, not an ID

You also appear to have extra `{}`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52gnczbr/)

Answer (score 0):

The below approach is simpler and much clear, no need for `isEmpty()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $slider = $('.slider');
    var $slider2 = $('#slider-2');
    $slider2
        .toggleClass("desativa", !!$.trim($slider.html()))
        .toggleClass("ativa", !$.trim($slider.html()));
</script>
```